# Laravel Forge: How to add multiple deploy keys to one Github repository

Tags: laravel, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, laravel-forge

I have one server on my Forge account with two sites. One is a production site while the other is a staging website. For example:

- domain.com
- test.domain.com

Both rely on the same Github repository, the staging site should be deployed when a commit is pushed to the develop branch while production should be deployed when anything is pushed to the main branch.

What did I do:

I added the deployment hook of both sites into the secrets of the Github repository:

- FORGE_DEPLOYMENT_HOOK_PRODUCTION
- FORGE_DEPLOYMENT_HOOK_STAGING

Then I created a Github action for both sites which starts on push to either branch and makes a curl request to the deployment hook:

```
name: Deploy production

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Deploy Site
        run: curl ${{ secrets.FORGE_DEPLOYMENT_HOOK_PRODUCTION }}
```

I added the site’s deploy key of the production site (domain.com) to the repository deploy keys. When I try to add the staging key (test.domain.com) I get the error: Key is already in use. If I check the key it is actually a different key except for the first x amount of characters. Because I can’t add the key the action only works for the production site and not the staging site. I get this error when deploying staging:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So my question is: how can I add the second deploy key? And if this is not possible, what would be the best way to setup my Github actions to achieve the same goal? I thought this to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else lands on this from Google. Laravel Forge supports separate deploy keys for each site even when you have multiple sites on one server. Go to Meta option after clicking into your site and add that deploy key to your github repo's Settings > Deploy Keys

Comment: In the Meta section of my site I only see those settings: domain, web directory, PHP version and tags.

Comment: @Baspa did you create the server as an "App Server" or "Web Server"? I believe you get more control using the App Server option. For me the site's deploy key shows in a card between PHP Version and Tags